# The continuity of the function $F(y)=\int_0^1 \frac{yf(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Considering the continuity of the function $F(y)=\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{yf(x)}{x^2+y^2}\,dx$, with $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0;1]$.

I will consider $y>0, \, y<0 \, \text{and} \, y=0$.

**1.** Consider $y=y_0>0$.
Then, $\exists \, c, \, d: 0<c<y_0<d$.

And, we have $\dfrac{yf(x)}{x^2+y^2}$  is continuous on $D: 0 \le x \le 1, \, c \le y\le d$.

So, $F(y)$ is continuous  on $[c;d]$, or $F(y)$ is continuous at the point $y=y_0$.

**2.** Consider $y=y_0<0$. Proof is as same as above.

**3.** Consider $y=0$. I think it isn't continuous at this point. However, I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Are you missing a $dx$ or a $dy$? Is the $f(x)$ factor definitely meant to be that instead of $f(y)$?

Comment: You should take a look at what happens when $f\equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: @J.G: No, I don't miss any $dx$ or $dy$.

Comment: @Matthew Pilling: Is your idea in the case $f \equiv 1$, it isn't continuous at $y = 0$ so $F(y)$ isn't continuous at $y = 0$?

Comment: Yes. I am saying $F$ doesn't have to be continuous at $y=0$

Comment: @MrCR: Are you still looking for solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show continuity of $F$, it is enough to study continuity of $G(y)=\int^1_0\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}\,dx$, for then $F(y)=yG(y)$ and $y\mapsto y$ is continuous.

Here we only prove continuity at any $y_0\neq0$. For all $y\in B(y_0;|y_0|)$
\begin{align}
|G(y)-G(y_0)|&\leq\int^1_0|f(x)|\Big|\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2_0}\Big|\,dx\\
&\leq \|f\|_\infty\int^1_0\frac{|y^2-y^2_0|}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2_0)}\,dx\\
&\leq \|f\|_\infty|y^2-y^2_0|\frac{1}{y^2y^2_0}\xrightarrow{y\rightarrow y_0}0
\end{align}

Continuity at $y=0$ requires conditions about intergrability of $\int^1_0x^{-2}f(x)\,dx$.